# WaitForSeconds Not Working[c#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was making a game using the **Unity 3d** game engine, and I was using `WaitForSeconds`, but I keep running into various errors depending on what I change. Here is my code (without the `WaitForSeconds`):

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {
    public int attack = 1;
    public ParticleSystem MA;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        MA.enableEmission = false;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)){

            attack++;
            if(attack > 3){

                attack = 1;

            }
            print (attack);
        }
        if(attack == 1){
            if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)){

                print ("punch");


            }
        }

        if(attack == 2){

            if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)){

                /*if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)){
                    WaitForSeconds magicdelay = new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
                    yield return magicdelay;

                    /*MA.enableEmission = true;
                yield return WaitForSeconds(1f);
                MA.enableEmission = false;

                }*/

                print ("magic");
                MA.enableEmission = true;
                //I need help with the WaitForSeconds her
            }


            }
        }



    }
```

I tried `YieldInstruction WaitForSeconds = (int)1f;` multiple times, but that didn't work. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Unity3d coroutines to solve the problem.

There are some useful links that can help:

1. [Unity3D coroutine class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)
2. [How to start Unity3D coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)){

   StartCoroutine("Magic");

}

IEnumerator Magic(){

    print ("magic");
    MA.enableEmission = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    MA.enableEmission = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine (MyCoroutine ());
}

IEnumerator MyCoroutine ()
{   
    while(true) 
    {
        Debug.Log(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```